# Аналог питоновского ord('x') на Си

Tags: c

Каков аналог питоновского ord('x') на Си ?

ord('x') даёт 120.

Comment: Просто `'x'`. Не шутка.

Comment: В Си нету понятия "символ" такоко как в питоне, паскале и т п, данные любой переменной могут трактоваться как символ, и как число одновременно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Никаких `(int)'x'` [не нужно](https://ideone.com/rIuKtf):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x = 'x';
int main(void) {

    printf("%d  %d\n", x, 'x');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: пока это просто 'x' - да, не нужно, потому что он и так int. Но если там char, то лучше сделать явно.

Answer (score 4):

```
#include <stdio.h>
int x = (int)'x';
int main(void) {

    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В Си литерал в одинарных кавычках и так `int`.